# Unity - Rigidbody joint inheriting only position?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I was wondering if it was possible to have a joint inherit only the position of the object it is attached to. I'd like to be able to control the rotation of it independently using a controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can't subvert Unity's hierarchy directly but you can do something like:

```
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Inverse (transform.parent.rotation);
```

Put that in a script and attach it to the child and that child will negate its parent rotation.  Keep in mind that if you want to rotate that child you need to apply that rotation to localRotation **after** inverting the parent.

Alternatively you could write a tracking script that updates position:

```
Transform follow; // set to object you're following.

void Update() {
    transform.position = follow.position;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In the end I went for the alternative of not having the object in the hierarchy and following position. I'll look up Quaternion Inverse though, that might be useful in the future.